GitHub self-hosted runner for other branches are not pulling the latest changes
I have the following YAML file. On every push to the branch, it should pull the latest code, build, and restart the service. It is running successfully on every push but when I SSH into the server, the changes are not pulled. When I run git pull origin dev, only then the changes are pulled. I have the similar YAML for another repository in the same organization for the frontend, and it is working fine for that.
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [22.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: cd /home/ubuntu/<project-name>-dev/<projec-name>-backend
    - run: git pull origin dev
    - name: Save environment variables
      run:
        echo "PORT=4000" >> .env &&
        echo "SOCKET_PORT=4002" >> .env
    - name: Test environment variables
      run:
        cat .env
    - run: npm ci
    - run: CI='' && npm run build
    - run: sudo systemctl restart <project-name>.service

Additional Information:
I have two repositories in the organization (for frontend and backend). Both deployed on EC2. Initially, had only one action and one runner for frontend (main branch). Now, using the same runner, I have added 3 more actions (frontend dev, backend main, backend dev) all of which are showing the above mentioned problematic behavior.
I was expecting to:

Action running on every push to dev (working)
Changes should be pulled on the server (not working)
Project should be built and service should be restarted (not working)


Many things could be wrong here so here are my suggestions to better narrow down the issue.

If you want the project in a specific path, checkout to it directly using the checkout action.
Specify working-directory for subsequent steps where applicable.

You should also note that cd in one step does not affect subsequent steps. Each step is a fresh shell invocation.
Here's how I'd write this:
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]

env:
  PROJECT_DIR: /home/ubuntu/<project-name>-dev/<projec-name>-backend
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [22.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        path: ${{ env.PROJECT_DIR }}

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'

    - name: Save environment variables
      run: |
        echo "PORT=4000" >> .env &&
        echo "SOCKET_PORT=4002" >> .env
      working-directory: ${{ env.PROJECT_DIR }}

    - name: Test environment variables
      run:
        cat .env
      working-directory: ${{ env.PROJECT_DIR }}

    - run: npm ci
      working-directory: ${{ env.PROJECT_DIR }}

    - run: CI='' && npm run build
      working-directory: ${{ env.PROJECT_DIR }}

    - run: sudo systemctl restart <project-name>.service
      working-directory: ${{ env.PROJECT_DIR }}


Thank you for the response. I will try this out and update here. But I wonder why it is working for the frontend repository.

Error: Repository path '/home/ubuntu/<projname>-dev/<projname>-backend' is not under '/home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/<projname>-backend/<projname>-backend'
Received this on actions/checkout step after implementing above YML file :(

Also, just noticed that he code inside '/home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/<projname>-backend/' is the latest one after the pipeline execution, but /home/ubuntu/<projname>-dev/<projname>-backend still contains the old code..

Make sure the path is consistent. If /home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/<projname>-backend/ is updated, why not just add a final step to copy the content from there to wherever you need it to be?
